# Open docx Sharepoint LIke

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, ms-word

Im trying to open a .docx File like Sharepoint does.

I've set up an apache2 web server such as the webdav part.

I know that it works with the following small javascript Code:

> var obj = new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3');

But when I use that piece of code I've got the Problem that it opens the .docx with the specified edit bar in Word, but if I click on edit the document stays in read only mode.

What could be the problem ?
Below you find my apache/webdav config part.

Another question is, that this piece of code will not work in FF because of the ActiveXObject, has anybody any idea what I could do that it also works in FF ?

Beacause we have already a big application for wich im trying to implement this, it isn't an opinion for us to switch the whole application to sharepoint.

apache 2 conf:

```
DavLockDB WebDAV/Locks
Directory Uploads
Dav on

ForceType text/plain

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Mein WebDAV"
AuthUserFile C:\Users

Require valid-user

AllowOverride None

Options Indexes
```

Sincerly
k3n0b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that my WebDAV Folder was in the same structure as the http docs.
I think it was that, because when i defined another Folder outside of the http docs path it started to work.

All you need is the small piece of javascript:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3');
obj.EditDocument('https://localhost/uploads/****.docx');
```

and a correct configured webdav in apache2.

Now I just have to handle how it works in ff, chrome, etc.